# modernizr CSS3 Animation fallback to swf

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

At the current time, i have a rather nice CSS3 animation, however i am required to provide a fallback option for browsers that do not support CSS3 animations (IE8 being the target)

I am required to use modernizr to make thinks easier, however i'm unsure of how to go about checking if the browser supports CSS animations, if it does, great, carry on, if not, display a flash version in the form of a swf instead.

CSS Below(Warning: theres alot!):

```
#animation
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
background:url('Images/Animation/SkyBG.png');
}

#rain
{
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
background: url('Images/Animation/RainDrop.png');
-webkit-animation-name: rain;
-webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rain {
 0% {background-position: 0px 0px; opacity:0;}
50%{opacity: 1;}
 100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px; opacity: 0;}
}




#soil
{
width: 700px;
height: 150px;
background:url('Images/Animation/BGGround.png') no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 750px;
z-index: 5;
}

#items
{
width:700px;
height: 400px;
top:623px;
position: absolute;
}

#Seed1
{
float:left;
width: 60px;
height: 110px;
background:url('Images/Animation/Seed.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 25px 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 140px;
}

#Seed2
{
float:left;
width: 60px;
height: 110px;
background:url('Images/Animation/Seed2.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 40px 55px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 140px;
}

#Seed3
{
float:left;
width: 60px;
height: 140px;
background:url('Images/Animation/Seed3.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 65px 80px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 125px;
}

#Seed4
{
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 170px;
background:url('Images/Animation/Seed4.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 125px 225px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

#Seed5
{
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 225px;
background:url('Images/Animation/Seed5.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 125px 225px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 20px;
}





#sun {
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: red;
position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: rise 10s linear 3s 1 normal both;
-webkit-animation-delay: 21s;
  -moz-animation: rise 10s linear 3s 1 normal both;
  -ms-animation: rise 10s linear 3s 1 normal both;
  -o-animation: rise 10s linear 3s 1 normal both;
  animation: rise 10s linear 3s 1 normal both;
z-index: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rise {
  0% {
    width: 12.5px;
    height: 12.5px;
    left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,0,1);
  }
  100% {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 80%;
    top: -20%;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px 45px rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes show
{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes infoboxshow
{
0% {opacity:0;}
50%{opacity:1;}
}


#Seed1
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 5;
position:absolute;
opacity:0;
}

#infoBox1
{
width: 400px;
height: 40px;
background:#f5cf26;
position: absolute;
bottom: 475px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lemon', cursive;
-webkit-animation-name: infoboxshow;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#Seed2
{

z-index: 15;
position:absolute;
left: 125px;
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#infoBox2
{
width: 400px;
height: 40px;
background:#f5cf26;
position: absolute;
bottom: 475px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lemon', cursive;
-webkit-animation-name: infoboxshow;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#Seed3
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 15;
position:absolute;
left: 250px;
opacity:0;
}

#infoBox3
{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background:#f5cf26;
position: absolute;
bottom: 425px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
font-size: 24px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Lemon', cursive;
-webkit-animation-name: infoboxshow;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#Seed4
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 15;
position:absolute;
left: 350px;
opacity:0;
}

#infoBox4
{
width: 400px;
height: 70px;
background:#f5cf26;
position: absolute;
bottom: 450px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
font-size: 24px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Lemon', cursive;
-webkit-animation-name: infoboxshow;
-webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#Seed5
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 31s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 15;
position:absolute;
left: 500px;
opacity:0;
}

#infoBox5
{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background:#f5cf26;
position: absolute;
bottom: 425px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
font-size: 24px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Lemon', cursive;
-webkit-animation-name: infoboxshow;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 31s;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr would be easier. Just use `Modernizr.cssanimations`. 
Exemplar:

```
<!-- ET CETERA -->
<head>
<!-- ET CETERA -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
         /* use jQuery to replace CSS3 animations with SWF
            you may want to use JavaScript, but jQuery is just easy for me
         */
    }
</script>
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

For cleaner aspect, in the if statement, use jQuery to append the  for a different stylesheet, e.g.:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-alternative.css">');
```

Comment: Could you provide any hints on what to write in the If statement to replace the animation?